# After Activity is destroyed: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am receiving this exception and I simply can't figure out why:

> Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState.

This is how I'm adding the first fragment when I my Activity inside `onCreate()`:

```
new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            final FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .add(id, fragment)
                    .commit();
        }
    });
```

Inside that first `fragment` I have a button which leads to another `fragment`. I navigate to another `fragment` like this:

```
new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            final FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .addToBackStack(fragment.getClass().getName())
                    .add(id, fragment)
                    .commit();
        }
    });
```

First time when I open my app, initial `fragment` shows normally and I can navigate to another `fragment` without problem. I can also navigate back to first `fragment` by calling `popBackstack()` or `onBackPressed()` on my `Activity`. Navigation works no matter how many times I go back and forth.

The problem occurs if I open app for the first time, initial `fragment` appears and then I click back button which closes the app. In this case, when I open the app second time and click on a button which leads to another `fragment`, I'm getting that exception.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you posting a `Runnable` to a `Handler` just to add a `Fragment`?

Comment: @GeorgeMulligan, desperate try to make it work :)

Comment: You shouldn't need it so you can go ahead and remove it. Is there a stack trace in logcat when it prints that message? If so can you add it.

Comment: Post the contents of your onBackPressed() method in the Activity in question.  Pretty sure I know what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to ur activity. Hope it solves

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    if (outState.isEmpty()) {
        outState.putBoolean("bug:fix", true);
    }
}
```